# Borrowing issues using variables wrapped in Arc<Mutex<>> in Rust

Tags: rust, struct, mutex, automatic-ref-counting, ownership

1. The code below can work.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test{
    str1 : Option<String>,
    str2 : Option<String>,
}
fn main() {
    let mut test = Test{
        str1 : Some(String::from("str1")),
        str2 : Some(String::from("str2"))
    };
    let str1 = test.str1.as_mut().unwrap();
    let str2 = test.str2.as_mut().unwrap();
    *str1 = String::from("nonono1");
    *str2 = String::from("nonono2");
    println!("{:?}", test);
}
```

2. The code with Arc<Mutex<>> like this can work.

```
use std::sync::{
    Arc, Mutex
};
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test{
    str1 : Option<String>,
    str2 : Option<String>,
}
fn main() {
    let test = Test{
        str1 : Some(String::from("str1")),
        str2 : Some(String::from("str2"))
    };
    let test = Arc::new(Mutex::new(test));
    let mut test = test.lock().unwrap();
    let str1 = test.str1.as_mut().unwrap();
    *str1 = String::from("nonono1");
    let str2 = test.str2.as_mut().unwrap();
    *str2 = String::from("nonono2");
    println!("{:?}", test);
}
```

3. But the other code cannot work.

```
use std::sync::{
    Arc, Mutex
};
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test{
    str1 : Option<String>,
    str2 : Option<String>,
}
fn main() {
    let test = Test{
        str1 : Some(String::from("str1")),
        str2 : Some(String::from("str2"))
    };
    let test = Arc::new(Mutex::new(test));
    let mut test = test.lock().unwrap();
    let str1 = test.str1.as_mut().unwrap();
    let str2 = test.str2.as_mut().unwrap();
    *str1 = String::from("nonono1");
    *str2 = String::from("nonono2");
    println!("{:?}", test);
}
```

4. It seems that I cannot borrow two deffierent part of a Struct wrapped in Arc<Mutex<>>.And I can do this in the first code.

I want to mutably borrow two parts of a structure wrapped with Arc<Mutex<>> at the same time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you call [`lock()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.lock) it doesn't actually return `&mut Test`, it returns [`MutexGuard<Test>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html). Then when you access a field, it is accessed through the [`impl DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html#impl-DerefMut-for-MutexGuard%3C%27_,+T%3E) on `MutexGuard`. Dereferencing through [`DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html) causes the whole `MutexGuard` to be mutably borrowed, instead of just the field when you otherwise access it directly.

You can resolve the issue, by upfront dereferencing `MutexGuard` into `&mut Test` by doing:

```rust
let mut test = test.lock().unwrap();
let test: &mut Test = &mut test;
```

Which when putting it all together, looks like this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=57b9699372fbaab032196f6ad9d0b77a)):

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test{
    str1 : Option<String>,
    str2 : Option<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let test = Test{
        str1 : Some(String::from("str1")),
        str2 : Some(String::from("str2"))
    };
    let test = Arc::new(Mutex::new(test));
    
    let mut test = test.lock().unwrap();
    let test: &mut Test = &mut test;
    
    let str1 = test.str1.as_mut().unwrap();
    let str2 = test.str2.as_mut().unwrap();
    *str1 = String::from("nonono1");
    *str2 = String::from("nonono2");
    println!("{:?}", test);
}
```