# Cannot combine two lines in one when RwLock is used

Tags: rust, rwlock

I am experimenting with Rust and ran into something very unexpected.

If I wrap state in a RwLock, then I cannot combine two statements using this state into a single one. If I remove the RwLock and use state directly, this works.

```rust
use parking_lot::{RwLock};

pub struct State {
    pub current: u8,
    pub history: Vec<u8>,
}

fn main() {
    let locked = RwLock::new(
        State {
            current: 10,
            history: Vec::new(),
        });
    // type: lock_api::rwlock::RwLockWriteGuard<parking_lot::raw_rwlock::RawRwLock, playground::State>
    let mut state = locked.write();

    // Works as two statements
    let old = std::mem::replace(&mut state.current, 5);
    state.history.push(old);

    // Fails as one statement
    // Error: cannot borrow `state` as mutable more than once at a time
    state.history.push(std::mem::replace(
        &mut state.current, 
        5,
    ));
}
```

Can someone explain what is happening?

EDIT: I have seen answers like [Error while trying to borrow 2 fields from a struct wrapped in RefCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060266/error-while-trying-to-borrow-2-fields-from-a-struct-wrapped-in-refcell). This is not the same question! This is about code that becomes invalid if and only if  two statements are nested. Something that I have only seen in Rust and no other language.

This artifaft also only appears when an RwLock is used.

Comment: This answer is for a mutex guard, not a rw guard. But the reason is the same

Comment: The best I can make out of the thread is: It's a weird compiler thing. This may be truth but is very unsatisfying.

Comment: Try reading this/my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78181631/2470818) instead, it might be more clear explaining the _why_ instead of just the _how_. Just replace `MutexGuard` with `RwLockWriteGuard`. In short, you have a `RwLockWriteGuard` not a `State`. So to access `State` fields, it uses `Deref`, which causes the whole struct to be borrowed

Comment: That clears part of it up. The one thing I am unclear about: Shouldn't the inner statement be evaluated first and then the outer statement, just as if you evaluate it line by line? Why is the nesting of statements making a difference? This is completely alien to me from all other languages I have seen so far.

Comment: Rust evaluates expressions from left to right, so it first evaluates `&mut state.history` which takes a mutable borrow on `state`, then it tries to evaluate `replace`, which attempts to take a second mutable borrow on `current`. That is why if you read the compiler error message it labels `state` as the "first mutable borrow".

Comment: Also this is one of the situations where `let` doing pattern matching is useful: while the compiler is not able to split borrows through a `DerefMut` (as that is essentially a function call) it's happy with `let State {current, history} = &mut *locked.write()`.

Comment: @Masklinn It's happy because of the `&mut *`, you might as well just do `let state = &mut *locked.write()`.

Comment: Thank you both, this is so helpful. I have learned:
1. Rust is evaluated from left to right and not inner to outer, which can influence borrowing.
2. By de-referencing I can borrow the underlying object (here hidden behind a RwLockWriteGuard), which I can then manipulate later.

Comment: For "left to right, not inner to outer" - it might be helpful to think of methods in their unsugared form, i.e. with `foo.bar(baz)` replaced with `FooType::bar(foo, baz)`. In this case, it's clear that receiver and arguments are at the same level, there's no "inner and outer".

Comment: If I "unsugar" the method it would look like this: Vector::push(state.history, std::mem::replace(&mut state.current, 5)) -- There is still an inner and outer here. Or am I missing something?

Comment: On second thought, you are right this helps. Normalized, the left to right direction is clear. Thank you!